# Appending text files using buffered type writer java

Tags: java

I'm trying to store data that is being inputted by a user and store it in a text file to be manipulated later on, I'm having problems with it keep on overwriting the first lines on data code below:

```
public void AddDataToFile(int i)

{
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./Cat Info.txt"));

        Cat catCurrent;
        catCurrent = catPenArray [i];            
        writer.append("Pen Number " + (i + 1));
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("Cat Name " + catCurrent.CatName);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("Cat Gender " + catCurrent.Gender);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("Chip Number " + catCurrent.ChipNumber);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("Arival Date " + catCurrent.ArrivalDate);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("Departure Date " + catCurrent.DepartureDate);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("How often fed " + catCurrent.HowOftenFed);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("Type Of food " + catCurrent.Food);
        writer.newLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `BufferedWriter` isn't the problem - it's the way you're constructing the `FileWriter`. You can simply use the [constructor overload which takes an `append` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.lang.String-boolean-):

```
new FileWriter("./Cat Info.txt", true)
```

Personally I would avoid using `FileWriter` at all though: it doesn't allow you to specify the encoding, which means it will always use the platform-default encoding. I prefer to use `FileOutputStream`, and wrap it in an `OutputStreamWriter`, specifying the encoding explicitly (usually as UTF-8). Again, `FileOutputStream` has a constructor allowing you to append instead of overwriting.